# Nested class declarations with multiple template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, typename

A bit stupified by why the following complies just fine:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    template<int i>
    struct Bar {
        typedef int BarSizeType;
    };
};

template<typename T, int i>
void do_something(typename Foo<T>::Bar<i>::BarSizeType arg) {
    // ...
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
struct Foo {
  template<int i>
  struct Bar {
    typedef int BarSizeType;
  };
};

template<typename T, int i>
void do_something(typename Foo<T, T>::Bar<i>::BarSizeType arg) {
  // ...
}
```

The compilation errors are:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '<'
>   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>   error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>   error C2039: 'BarSizeType' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Any way I can make this compile, without making drastic changes to the code? I'm using vs2012 compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in MSVC; both are incorrect.  You need to write `template`:

```
void do_something(typename Foo<T>::template Bar<i>::BarSizeType arg) {
                                   ^ here

void do_something(typename Foo<T, T>::template Bar<i>::BarSizeType arg) {
                                      ^ and here
```

For more information, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)